# Cross Section Area

Tags: material-science, metals

When bending sheet metal in a press brake, it stretches slightly. For example, if I had a piece of steel 200 mm long by 1 mm thick and bent it in half, the two legs will each be longer than 100 mm so it’s obvious that the material has deformed and stretched a tiny bit. But what about its cross sectional area? Does that remain the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming negligible change in density, conservation of mass dictates the cross sectional area must decrease if the length increases so that the volume, and thus mass, remains the same.

Hope this helps.